# Guice, Generics, and TypeLiterals

Tags: generics, guava, guice, typeliteral

Suppose I have this:

```
public class Foo<T> {
    @Inject public Foo(Class<T> tClass);
}

public class FooProvider<T> implements Provider<Foo<T>> {
    @Inject private TypeLiteral<T> type;
    @Override
    public Foo<T> get() {
        Class<T> rawType = (Class<T>) type.getRawType();
        return new Foo<>(rawType);
    }
}
```

If I have, in a module,

```
bind(Foo.class).toProvider(FooProvider.class);
```

Would it automatically bind `Foo<Integer>`, `Foo<String>`, and so on, or would they have to be provided separately?  Also suppose that I cannot modify `Foo` so that it takes a `TypeLiteral<T>` instead of a `Class<T>`.

Related question: suppose instead I have Guava's `TypeToken<T>` (or other comparable "type token" class), and I have a provider that converts a `TypeLiteral<T>` to a `TypeToken<T>`.  Will a similar principle work?

Comment: Why not try it yourself?

Comment: IMO guice does a poor job of handling generics. An times it can seem like a quite invlived process to get generics bound correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The given binding

```
bind(Foo.class).toProvider(FooProvider.class);
```

will only bind only bind the class "Foo" (without specifying the generic type) to the provider.  You'll need to use a TypeLiteral to specify the generic. You can get the desired behavior with the following statement:

```
bind(new TypeLiteral<Foo>(){}).toProvider(FooProvider.class);
```

Comment: Still stubbornly refuses to compile for me.  Says that `FooProvider.class` cannot be cast to a `Class<? extends Provider<? extends Foo>>`.  Any tweaks so that it can work...?

Comment: I think this answer address the spirit of the question but does not solve your problem. See my other answer to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

Class:

```
public class Foo<T> {
    @Inject public Foo(Class<T> tClass);
}
```

I'm guessing that you want the JIT the supply the generic types automatically when injecting the class, but that's not going to happen. That's not how Guice's JIT works. You'll need to bind each of the generic types you plan on using. See the following code snippet (note that we are not binding Foo, we are biding the class that will be injected into Foo):

```
bind(new TypeLiteral<Class<MyType>>(){}).toInstance(MyType.class);
```

To get the instance, you need to define the type as the generic.

```
@Inject Foo<MyType> foo
```

And to poll it directly from the injector, you'll need to be specific about the generic type

```
injector.getInstance(Key.get((new TypeLiteral<Foo<MyType>>(){})));
```